# Laravel | Get the dropdown selected value after submit

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to get the dropdown selected value after submitting the form.

If I run a dd($_REQUEST); I can find the submitted value into an array :

```
"ordersdetail-productnameID" => array:1 [▼ 0 => "1" ]
```

I tried may variantes to get to my value from the array but without success :

```
$productnameID = array( 
    'ordersdetail-productnameID' => $input['productnameID']); or
$productnameID = $request->input('orders_detail.0.productnameID ');
```

Would appreciate some expertise.

Thanks, Cheers, Marc

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this kind of solution in the controller?

If the name of the function in your controller is myFunction,

```
public function myFunction(Request $request){

    $productnameID = $request->productnameID;
    dd($productnameID);

}
```

check the output. You'll get the ID,

Comment: Thanks but I don't get the value with this. Instead of "1" which I get with dd($_REQUEST); I get a Null value with your method

Comment: ok then change the name of the select to productNameID

<select name="productNameID">

Answer (score 0):

Solution is : $productnameID = $_REQUEST['ordersdetail-productnameID'][0];